# I have a Triban RC100 (Women's bike, small) what size bottom bracket does it have?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, replacement

I recently crashed my bike and bent the stock crankset so I am thinking of buying a new one and replacing it but for that I need to know what size bottom bracket comes with a stock Triban RC 100 women's bike (Size: Small)?
Also, I am replacing the stock with a Shimano Sora, do I need a different chain for that?

Answer (score 1):

This bike has a BSC/British thread bottom bracket shell, which is the most common. The Sora chainset will be fine for most applications where a 50/34 ratio is needed. It is optimised for a 9-speed chain so consider choosing Claris if you have an 8-speed system or Tiagra if it's 10. They all use the same bottom bracket system and are physically interchangable in that sense, as they all use HollowtechII style bottom bracket bearings.

The replacement will be a decent upgrade over the bike's original chainset.